# TypeError: users() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to solve this problem for hours but I can't understand what is "self" for users.

```
async def giveaway(ctx):
    user_list = []
    reaction = discord.Reaction
    await ctx.send('')
    time.sleep(5)
    users = await reaction.users()
    async for user in users:
        user_list.append(user)
```

Comment: is this method part of a class?

Comment: no, it's just a bot that gets usernames and append them in a list.

Comment: `reaction = discord.Reaction` this definitely isn't what you're trying to do.  Assuming you're trying to get a specific reaction from a specific message, what do you know about that reaction?

Comment: I don't try to get specific reaction, i think i made it wrong, can you help me for the good code? I am trying to make a giveaway bot, I just need to get usernames in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to do.  The bot will send a message, add a reaction to it, wait some amount of time, then randomly select one of those people

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from typing import Optional
from random import choice
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def giveaway(ctx, timeout: Optional[int] = 60, *, text = "Giveaway"):
    emoji = "\N{HAPPY PERSON RAISING ONE HAND}"
    message = await ctx.send(text)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await asyncio.sleep(timeout)
    message = await message.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
    reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=emoji)
    users = [user async for user in reaction.users() if user.id != bot.user.id]
    await ctx.send(f"Congrats {choice(users).mention}")

bot.run("token")
```